# Stuck on Dynamic Controls, Viewstate, and Postback. Simplified example

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, postback, viewstate

I've been reading posts and links, and articles about viewstate, and statebag, and postback and page creation.

I'm a pretty decent amateur, but this one just isn't sinking in, could someone show me an example of how this might be done?

OK, here is what I am trying to do with this example

Create a table where the left column has LinkButtons

When each linkButton is clicked it opens a bunch of Imagebuttons in the right column

Each Imagebutton then pops up a message

The problem is the imagebutton does not trigger the message

here is the front end:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="simple.aspx.vb" Inherits="simple" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>simple</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:Table id="MainTable" runat="server">
<asp:TableRow>

<asp:TableCell ID ="cell1" BackColor="LightBlue" />

<asp:TableCell ID ="cell2" BackColor="LightBlue" />

</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code:

```
Partial Class simple
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    Dim NewTableButton As LinkButton = New LinkButton
    NewTableButton.Text = "Text Created from 1st SQL Query"
    AddHandler NewTableButton.Click, AddressOf LoadContacts

    cell1.Controls.Add(NewTableButton)

End Sub

Protected Sub LoadContacts(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim TextPassedfromLinkButton As String = sender.text.ToString

    Dim imgGear As New ImageButton
    imgGear.ImageUrl = "../graphics/gear.jpg"
    imgGear.AlternateText = "Text Created from 2nd SQL Query using the " _
 & TextPassedfromLinkButton & " as a query parameter"
    AddHandler imgGear.Click, AddressOf message

    cell2.Controls.Add(imgGear)

End Sub

Protected Sub message(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim strText As String = sender.text.ToString
    Dim alertString As String = "alert('" & strText & "');"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "showalert", alertString, True)

End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the view source after you click the button that should popup the message

```
 <table id="MainTable">
 <tr>
 <td id="cell1" style="background-color:LightBlue;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl03&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Text Created from 1st SQL Query</a></td>
 <td id="cell2" style="background-color:LightBlue;"><input type="image" name="ctl04" src="../graphics/gear.jpg" alt="Text Created from 2nd SQL Query using the Text Created from 1st SQL Query as a query parameter" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

So in the meantime I got this to work (updated 10:49 est)

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    Dim NewTableButton As LinkButton = New LinkButton
    NewTableButton.Text = "Text Created from 1st SQL Query"
    'AddHandler NewTableButton.Click, AddressOf LoadContacts
    AddHandler NewTableButton.Click, Function() LoadContacts(NewTableButton.Text)

    cell1.Controls.Add(NewTableButton)

    If IsPostBack Then
        LoadContacts(NewTableButton.Text)
    End If

End Sub

Private Function LoadContacts(strText As String) As Integer

    Dim TextPassedfromLinkButton As String = strText

    Dim imgGear As New ImageButton
    imgGear.ID = "uniquename"
    EnableViewState = False
    imgGear.ImageUrl = "../graphics/gear.jpg"
    imgGear.AlternateText = "Text Created from 2nd SQL Query using the " & TextPassedfromLinkButton & " as a query parameter"
    AddHandler imgGear.Click, AddressOf message

    cell2.Controls.Add(imgGear)

    Return 0

End Function
```

The only problem is I get 2 Identical imgGears

[duplicate buttons http://reinsmith.net/graphics/simple1.png](http://reinsmith.net/graphics/simple1.png)
[message displayed http://reinsmith.net/graphics/simple2.png](http://reinsmith.net/graphics/simple2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are instantiating the imgGear button *during the event handler of another button*.

It seems totally logical to do so, but the event handler for imgGear will never be triggered if imgGear is created and added to the control tree too late in the page lifecycle, e.g. in an event handler or during OnPreRender.

It is very hard to achieve what you are trying to do using standard .Net practices...I have never managed it. You may also notice a text box added during an event handler doesn't usually retain its value on postback, again because it has been added too late in the page lifecycle.

You really need to detect the context during OnInit or CreateChildControls, because a button instantiated and added to the control tree during that phase *will* have its handler triggered.

I have developed a work around though...and like most work arounds it's not pretty...but it can get you out of a tight spot:

During OnInit you can tell if your button caused the postback, if it's a member variable. Intialise the NewTableButton in the contructor...then you can detect if it was clicked during OnInit...

```
   Private NewTableButton as Button

   Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        NewTableButton = New LinkButton
        NewTableButton.Text = "Text Created from 1st SQL Query"
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
        cell1.Controls.Add(NewTableButton)
        If Not IsNothing(Page.Request(NewTableButton.UniqueID)) Then
           ' Create and add imgGear Button
           LoadContacts
        End If
    End Sub
```

However, the text box / drop down values are not available during OnInit using standard practices...so, you may have to a) Defer the reading of them until OnPreRender, or b) Use the Page.Request(Control.UniqueID) to read the value of input controls during OnInit.

This is one of the biggest issues I have with .Net web development, it causes headaches and I don't like work arounds...

I love to know if there was an alternative to this workaround, but It's the only way I've found to achieve what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: OK, now here's the fun part.  This is a simplified example.  What I'm really trying to do is first create a set of link buttons from an SQL query with customer names.  Then when the LinkButton is clicked take the individual customer name and display records that have the customer name.  for example individual contacts at each customer.  Then for each contact create a link or button to EDIT that individual contact in a modal popup.  So the override could work if I could detect the individual control that sent the request and pull some variable from it   does that make sense?

Comment: Dude, you've now changed the question. I helped you understand the original issue and gave you a workaround. It would be nice if you had showed your appreciation rather than changing the question.

Comment: My apologies, I do appreciate it and is working (I think) I've had lots of fires to put out these last few days and have been able to get back to it. Hopefully I'll be able to today.  Thanks again and no offense intended especially to one the few who were able to respond!

Comment: I can't say it enough, THANK YOU!  I finally took the time to understand your solution and of course it works.  I'm going to use it to rework my final setup.  Thanks again for reminding me to take the time needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in reference to the Page Lifecycle, and how events are wired up. When you're already to the event handler stage of the page lifecycle, it's too late to wire up events for new controls. You need to do things earlier in the process for this to work.

To solve the problem, I can think of 3 potential ways to do this that are more Webforms-friendly.

1. Use a Data-driven approach by creating a Repeater control, DataGridView, or similar and binding the results of your Sql query to that. Part of this solution may involve writing some raw html/javascript for use with the repeater, in conjunction with a WebMethod, to keep your events mainly client-side and avoid causing full postbacks at all. Given that we already know you have an SQL query, this seems like the most natural fit.
2. Create placeholder controls that are empty and have the `Visible` property set to `False` for every possible control you need. Then at run time assign data to the existing controls, and only set `Visible` to `True` for those controls you are actually using. This is often the best option when you know there will be a relatively small number of items, with a maximum upper bound.
3. Develop a custom control that encapsulates the ImageButton/Message/Event concept into a single control.

Additionally, your comment to another answer suggests that you may want to consider a separate page for viewing/editing an individual customer vs viewing all customers (perhaps with a querystring parameter). One this page, for the modal popup, I'd put that into a `div` where that data and everythign else to support the popup is *already loaded* at the start of the page, and just use javascript, rather than server-code, to alter the page DOM to show or hide the popup.